# pprint in clojure sublimeREPL

Tags: clojure, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

Is there a way to use pprint instead of regular print in clojure sublimeREPL

For the moment i had to wrap my code like that to do so:

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint (for [i (range 10)] {i {:times2 (* i 2) :times3 (* i 3)}}))
=>    ({0 {:times2 0, :times3 0}}
       {1 {:times2 2, :times3 3}}
       {2 {:times2 4, :times3 6}}
       {3 {:times2 6, :times3 9}}
       {4 {:times2 8, :times3 12}}
       {5 {:times2 10, :times3 15}}
       {6 {:times2 12, :times3 18}}
       {7 {:times2 14, :times3 21}}
       {8 {:times2 16, :times3 24}}
       {9 {:times2 18, :times3 27}})
```

sorry for the dummy example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with simple [nrepl middleware](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl#middleware), for example:

```
(defn pprint-middleware [h]
  (fn [{:keys [code op] :as msg}]
    (if (and (= op "eval") (not (empty? code)))
      (->> #(str "(clojure.pprint/pprint " % ")")
           (update-in msg [:code])
           h)
      (h msg))))
```

The easiest way to add it to your repl is to config `repl-options` in youe `project.clj`:

```
:repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [nrepl.utils/pprint-middleware]})
```

Here is the full `project.clj` example:

```
(defproject sample "0.1.0"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]]
  :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [sample.utils/pprint-middleware]})
```

Comment: silly question: where do i place this function in my project?

Comment: i've tried to place pprint-middleware in my "utils" namespace, then i've modified :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [pprint-middleware]} to :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [utils/pprint-middleware]} but it i've got an error when launch the repl

Comment: Try updating your `lein` with `lein upgrade`. Old versions have no support for `repl-options`.

Comment: it doesn't seems to change anything, here's the error message:   CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reply.exports, compiling:(/private/var/folders/3w/l39tm8z56cs2ypk389nv_7lh0000gn/T/form-init5267732350145682329.clj:1:8446) 

Error loading namespace; falling back to user

NullPointerException   clojure.pprint/column-writer/fn--7358 (column_writer.clj:78)